# How to find nearest points based on position?

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I have a group of spheres which are arranged like this:

[image]

Each sphere is equidistant to each other. For this my code is:

```
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.2);
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xe0e0e0
})

for (var zPos = -120, i = 0; zPos <= 120; zPos += 7, i++) {

    arr[i] = [];

    for (var xPos = -120, j = 0; xPos <= 120; xPos += 7, j++) {

        arr[i][j] = "(" + i + "," + j + ")";

        sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        sphere.position.set(xPos, 0, zPos);
        sphere.name = i + "-" + j;
        count++;
        sphere.receiveShadow = true;
        sphereMesh.add(sphere);
    }
    rows++;
}

scene.add(sphereMesh);
```

Here sphereMesh is a Group.

Now my problem is when I give a particular position as input the spheres which are near to the position with in some radius should get selected and they should change their color.

How to find the spheres near to that position given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just measure the distance between *givenPoint* and *sphere* and test it versus an arbitrary limit.
Just an examples, assuming *givenPoint* being a [THREE.Vector3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector2) and *sphere* being a [THREE.Mesh](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Mesh)

```
var limit = 2;
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sphere.position.x - givenPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(sphere.position.y - givenPoint.y));
if (distance > limit)
{
   // is out
} 
else
{
   // is in
}
```

You can then add several breakpoint in order to say how much a sphere is near the *givenPoint*, or better normalize it and get a scale:

```
var normalized = 1 - distance / limit
```